# Is there a way to use an IOS Clash of Clans Account on my Computer?

Tags: pc, clash-of-clans, ios

My IOS mobile Device fell and broke.

Is there any way to use my Clash of Clans account on my laptop instead of my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you had an iPhone since you did not precised it in the question, but you used the tag iOS. Anyways, if you had an android, all you have to do is replace "iOS" by "android" and "GameCenter" by "Google+" in my answer.

If you were not logged in GameCenter, your save might be lost until you get your phone repaired. You could try to contact the CoC support, but I can't guarantee they can do anything. If you were so, your will be able to get back your progression.

First of all, you have to download an iOS emulator. You can find some by searching on google, take the one that fit for you. Here is one : http://www.xpadian.com/.

Now, you have the you have to download Clash of Clan using the AppStore.

Finally, connect your brand new fake phone into GameCenter and your account should be back !

Answer (score 0):

**This** **is** **only** **if** **you're** **a Android user**

You can use an application called "Bluestacks" as this mobile gaming platform is used for playing games usually made for mobile devices and put on a PC

You can download it here and login to your Google Play account:http://www.bluestacks.com/download.html

Other wise if you are not a **Android User** and you are an IOS person you can still play Clash of Clans but will not be your usual village as you are not logged into your Google Play Account.

Comment: i need it to be in my pc

Comment: When you install Bluestacks and install clash of clans it will be added to your games and if you use google play then you can log into your account to use the village.

Comment: but i am not taking about android

Comment: Do you have an IOS device that was currently destroyed? If so I will try to help.

Comment: yes i have it right now

Answer (score 0):

If it was google account then it could have been possible but as it is an ios account there is not way you can go to pc with that as there are no ios emulator that can do it.

I suggest as easy way out.

Just open COC on iphone and link it to a google account and then come back to pc and use any emulator that you like and enjoy the game on pc.

There are also ways to install android on pc if you want like you install windows.

Check on google "Android-x86". Hope this help.